# Flutter> Patrol >Allure: Command for retrieve the results from the device (Windows)

Tags: flutter, allure, flutter-patrol

This commad doesn't work for me on Windows:

`adb exec-out sh -c 'cd /sdcard/googletest/test_outputfiles && tar cf - allure-results' | tar xvf - -C build/reports`

Issue:

tar.exe: Damaged tar archive

tar.exe: Retrying...

( Command comes from doc: https://patrol.leancode.co/integrations/allure)

Currently, I use:

1. `adb exec-out sh -c 'cd /sdcard/googletest/test_outputfiles && tar cf allure allure-results'`
2. ```
   adb pull /sdcard/googletest/test_outputfiles/allure build/reports
   ```
3. ```
   next move manullay to the correct path in project: build/reports/allure-results
   ```

   It works, but looking for simpe way...

   Maybe someone can provide, a way how to handle this with one command on Windows platform?